# Google lists Chemisty.SE in the books section!

Tags: discussion

Google considers us worthy to be results in the Books section.

[image]
https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=spdefghik

[image]
https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=chemistry+stack

Comment: Google Books lists on top single domain that it is able to identify from the query. If you type `pornhub`, you also get the main page on top of Google Books. It has nothing to do with being, ehhm, "worthy" (at least for the audience of this site:) ).

Comment: "*If you type pornhub, you also get the main page on top of Google Books.*" For someone to carry out such an experiment, @andselisk, you truly are... man of science! *Salutes* O:)

Comment: Note that searching for pornhub will likely not work in South Korea. \*runs before I am considered another man of science\*

Comment: @Jan But it might work in Japan... right? :D (And you needn't worry, I've always looked up to you as a man of science since well before that comment of yours transpired)

Comment: The real question is.... "Is Chemistry.SE a book!?" Also, [meta effect has done itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmlqh.png) (at least for me when opening the first link)